# Chrome, print and percent divs

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I'm designing a simple html page whose sole intent is to be printed. I don't care how it looks on screen but it must print on a SINGLE page (A4 or letter) and from any browser. Therefore I need to use divs sized only with percents.

The problem with the following skeleton code is that on Chrome print preview, the 2 words are displayed both on the first line, contrarily to what is displayed in the web page. I don't get this issue in FF and IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, div, p, span { margin:0px;padding:0px; }
    html, body { width:100%;height:100%;min-height:100%;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="height:70%;">
      first
    </div>

    <div style="height:30%;">
      second
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Letter is the smallest size of the so to say "standard" paper types.  It is a little wider than A4 though.  So why not constrain yourself to the height of Letter and the width of A4?  You'll want to incorporate some margin space anyways, which should account for a a good portion of width differences.

To that end, what about switching from percentages to actual inches or even millimeters (more precise).  CSS does support these units.

For example calculate your 70% of page size in millimeters for the tallest paper size you support and the smallest paper size you support.  Lets use Letter and A4.  So 70% of 279mm (Letter) = 195.3 rounded down (safer) to 195.  So put `min-height: 195mm;`  Then for A4 70% of 297 = 207.9 rounded down = 207 so `max-height: 207mm;`

Calculating for 30%...

```
min-height: 83mm;
max-height: 89mm;
```

Seems sound to me, not sure why it wouldn't work?

Comment: I will need to try this... Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use @media print,  check css media types and how to use it.
For example here is written sample, you can remove borders added just to test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    @media screen {
    html, body, div, p, span { margin:0px;padding:0px; }
    html, body { width:100%;height:100%;}
    div.first {height:70%; width:100%;   }
    div.second {height:30%; width:100%; }
    }
    @media print {
    html, body, div, p, span { margin:0px;padding:0px; }
    html, body { width:100%;height:100%;}
    div.first {height:70%; width:100%; border:1px solid red; display:block;   position:fixed; top:0; left:0;  }
    div.second {height:30%; width:100%; border:1px solid blue; display:block; position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; }

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="first">
     first
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      second
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: adding @media print around my styles does not change anything. Anyway, W3 says "Style rules outside of media rules apply to all media types that the style sheet applies to"

Comment: You completely changed the layout. I want a 70% high div at the top and the 30% high div underneath.

Comment: Hi, that was just example of how to use media types in css, updated example for you. (works for me!)

Comment: I confirm your example now works. But it has nothing to do with media print. You can remove all the media directives and keep only the styles under the media print. It works because you added position:fixed. While it looks like a workaround, it doesn't tell why only Chrome needs this, what is the reasoning behind, and how it will behave well I will add content and other relative constructs to this skeleton. Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: When printing, the width:100% on .first and .second does not goes 100% anymore. I also tried the same construct inside .first (adding 2 divs with percent sizes) and it does not work, which is logical since position:fixed works relatively to the window.

Comment: Looks like when it comes to print css in chrome, i may need to do more study.